# Зашифровать данные на C++

Tags: c++, криптография

Хочу реализовать систему зашифровки текста через C++.
Есть ли какая-нибудь функция по этому поводу?
Если нет, какой алгоритм предложите?

Comment: Слишком общий вопрос, нужны конкретные критерии. Алгоритмов тьма, функций для шифрования в стандартной библиотеке нет

Comment: если вас интересует эта задача с точки зрения учебной задачи, то можете реализовать "шифр цезаря" - очень простой в реализации алгоритм (но и весьма просто взламывается с помощью компьютера). Можно сделать и посложнее использовав алгоритм "энигмы" (но и он давольно просто ломается с помощью компьютера, хотя это и гораздо сложнее предыдущего алгоритма)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам поможет [Crypto++](https://www.cryptopp.com/). Сам пользовался, довольно удобно. К сожалению свой код показать не могу (закрытый проект), но пример брал [отсюда](https://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-beginners/thread1300736.html):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
 
#include <cryptopp/aes.h>
#include <cryptopp/modes.h>
#include <cryptopp/base64.h>
 
std::string encrypt(const std::string& str_in, const std::string& key)
{
    std::string str_out;
    CryptoPP::ECB_Mode<CryptoPP::AES>::Encryption encryption((byte*)key.c_str(), key.length());
 
    CryptoPP::StringSource encryptor(str_in, true, 
            new CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter(encryption, 
                new CryptoPP::Base64Encoder(
                    new CryptoPP::StringSink(str_out),
                    false // do not append a newline
                )
            )
    );
    return str_out;
}
 
std::string decrypt(const std::string& str_in, const std::string& key)
{
    std::string str_out;
 
    CryptoPP::ECB_Mode<CryptoPP::AES>::Decryption decryption((byte*)key.c_str(), key.length());
 
    CryptoPP::StringSource decryptor(str_in, true, 
        new CryptoPP::Base64Decoder(
                new CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter(decryption, 
                    new CryptoPP::StringSink(str_out)
                )
        )
    );
    return str_out;
}
 
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::string str = "hello";
    std::string key = "0123456789123456";
    
    std::string str_encrypted, str_decrypted;
    
    try {
        str_encrypted = encrypt(str, key);
        str_decrypted = decrypt(str_encrypted, key);
    }
    catch (const CryptoPP::Exception& e) {
       std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    
    std::cout << "str_encrypted: " << str_encrypted << std::endl;
    std::cout << "str_decrypted: " << str_decrypted << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Ну или вот ещё вариант: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12307096/1597497

Comment: лучше бы взяли openssl

Comment: @Maggot Приведите пример, мне было бы тоже интересно

Comment: а что вас на opensslwiki заблочили? https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption или на поиске в стаке? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23433038/openssl-aes-cfb128-encrypt-c

Comment: Я намекаю на то что можно потратить пару минут и дать ответ в виде ответа. Более того, человек знакомый с областью способен дать короткий и достаточный ответ с примером.

Comment: поупражняетесь в просмотре информации перед ее подачей - вопрос является закрытым - публикация ответа не возможна

Comment: Вопрос закрылся после того, как я попросил привести пример. Впрочем, дискуссию тоже можно считать закрытой.

Comment: смешно просто...